# Cómo configurar una imagen como link de redirección en html

Tags: html, xhtml

Estaba estudiando por mi cuenta xhtml y css, mi duda es la siguiente:

¿Cómo configurar la página para que, al hacer click sobre una imagen, me redirija a la página de inicio? ¿Cómo se haría?

Comment: Te dejo un ejemplo: [demo](http://jsbin.com/xirene/edit?html,output)

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿por qué XHTML y no HTML5?

Answer (score 3):

Te dejo un ejemplo super sencilla pero funcional. Si quieres cambiar la direccion en donde te lleve la imagen debes cambiar la direccion que sale despues de "href=". Por otro lado si quieres cambiar la imagen debes cambiar donde sale "src=" e indicar la direccion o link donde tengas la imagen.

Aqui el ejemplo:

```
<html>
  <a href="http://www.google.cl">
      <img src="http://irishtaxi.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/clickme.jpg" alt="Imagen" />
  </a>
<html>
```

Saludos espero te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

en la primera respuesta esta todo claro.

a ora si quizás estas en la misma pagina y solo quieres navegar en ella que te lleve a una sección etc.

```
<a href="#inicio">
      <img src="ruta/de/tu/imagem.jpg"/>
  </a>


<section id="inicio">lorem loremloremloremloremloremloremloremlorem</section>
```